# Laravel Combine or Merge objects of two Collection in straight way

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach, collections

```php
$user = collect(["name"=>"sam","age"=>20],["name"=>"john","age"=>21],["name"=>"roz","age"=>19]);
```

---

```php
$car = collect(["name"=>"sam","car"=>"BMW"],["name"=>"john","car"=>"Audi"],["name"=>"roz","car"=>"Ford"]);
```

---

I want to merge or combine these two collection and get an output like this:

```php
$collection = (["name"=>"sam","age"=>20,"car"=>"BMW"],["name"=>"john","age"=>21,"car"=>"Audi"],["name"=>"roz","age"=>19,"car"=>"Ford"])
```

thank you for your support.

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the collections are ordered collections you can just loop over one of them and arrange your data:

```
/**
 * Merging the user and the car collections
 * 
 * @param Collection $users
 * @param Collection $cars
 * 
 * @return Collection
 */
function mergeUserCollections(Collection $users, Collection $cars): Collection
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($users as $index => $user) {
        $result[] = [
            'name' => $user['name'],
            'age' => $user['age'],
            'car' => $cars[$index]['car'],
        ];
    }

    return collect($result);
}


function getData()
{
    $users = collect([
        ["name"=>"sam", "age"=>20],
        ["name"=>"john", "age"=>21],
        ["name"=>"roz", "age"=>19]
    ]);
    $cars = collect([
        ["name"=>"sam", "car"=>"BMW"],
        ["name"=>"john", "car"=>"Audi"],
        ["name"=>"roz", "car"=>"Ford"]
    ]);

    $merged_data = mergeUserCollections($users, $cars);
}
```

If it's not then group by the cars collection with name:

```
/**
 * Merging the user and the car collections
 * 
 * @param Collection $users
 * @param Collection $cars
 * 
 * @return Collection
 */
function mergeUserCollections(Collection $users, Collection $cars): Collection
{
    $result = [];

    $users_cars = $cars->keyBy('name');

    foreach ($users as $index => $user) {
        $result[] = [
            'name' => $user['name'],
            'age' => $user['age'],
            'car' => $users_cars[$user['name']]['car'],
        ];
    }

    return collect($result);
}

function getData()
{
    $users = collect([
        ["name"=>"sam", "age"=>20],
        ["name"=>"john", "age"=>21],
        ["name"=>"roz", "age"=>19]
    ]);
    $cars = collect([
        ["name"=>"sam", "car"=>"BMW"],
        ["name"=>"john", "car"=>"Audi"],
        ["name"=>"roz", "car"=>"Ford"]
    ]);

    $merged_data = mergeUserCollections($users, $cars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$users = collect([["name"=>"sam","age"=>20],["name"=>"john","age"=>21],["name"=>"roz","age"=>19]]);
$cars = collect([["name"=>"sam","car"=>"BMW"],["name"=>"john","car"=>"Audi"],["name"=>"roz","car"=>"Ford"]]);

return $users->map(function ($item) use ($cars) {
        $car = $cars->first(fn ($value)=> $value['name'] === $item['name']);
        $item['car'] = $car['car'];
        return $item;
    })->all();
```

Note: the way you use the `collect` method is not going to give you what you want, you need to wrap the whole within an array like the code above.